glVertexAttribPointer not taking effect on first call
I'm using egui + glow in Rust. The latter should just be a wrapper layer and not be interfering, and I haven't identified any interference from the former.
I'm creating/binding a VAO, calling glVertexAttribPointer, and unbinding the VAO.
When I bind the VAO again to render, I get a garbage result unless I call glVertexAttribPointer again during the render loop. This second call only has to happen once - I can wrap it with std::sync::Once and all future succeed.
I called glGetVertexArrayIndexediv from C (glow doesn't expose it) during both setup and the render loop without the duplicate glVertexAttribPointers, and all values look correct, so the first calls are affecting the VAO, but the VAO is not affecting the draw call.
Failure case without duplicate calls:

Success case with duplicate calls:

use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use eframe::{egui::{self, CentralPanel, PaintCallback, Rect}, egui_glow::CallbackFn, glow::{self, HasContext, Program, Texture, UniformLocation, VertexArray}, App, CreationContext, Frame, NativeOptions};

type Gl = Arc<glow::Context>;

const SRC_FRAGMENT: &str = "
#version 430

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

in vec2 fragment_uv;

uniform sampler2D sampler;

void main() {
    color = texture(sampler, fragment_uv);
}
";
const SRC_VERTEX: &str = "
#version 430

layout(location = 0) in vec2 xy;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 uv;

out vec2 fragment_uv;

void main() {
    fragment_uv = uv;
    gl_Position = vec4(xy, 0, 1);
}
";

unsafe fn build_program(gl: &glow::Context, sources: &[(u32, &str)]) -> Program {
    let program = gl.create_program().unwrap();

    let mut shaders = Vec::with_capacity(sources.len());
    for (kind, src) in sources {
        let shader = gl.create_shader(*kind).unwrap();
        gl.shader_source(shader, src);
        gl.compile_shader(shader);
        if !gl.get_shader_compile_status(shader) {
            panic!("{}", gl.get_shader_info_log(shader));
        }
        gl.attach_shader(program, shader);

        shaders.push(shader);
    }

    gl.link_program(program);
    if !gl.get_program_link_status(program) {
        panic!("{}", gl.get_program_info_log(program));
    }

    for shader in shaders {
        gl.detach_shader(program, shader);
        gl.delete_shader(shader);
    }

    program
}

unsafe fn build_texture(gl: &Gl) -> Texture {
    let buffer = [
        255, 0, 0, 255, // red top left
        0, 255, 0, 255, // green top right
        0, 0, 255, 255, // blue bottom left
        0, 0, 0, 255    // black bottom right
    ];
    let texture = gl.create_texture().unwrap();
    gl.bind_texture(glow::TEXTURE_2D, Some(texture));
    gl.tex_parameter_i32(glow::TEXTURE_2D, glow::TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, glow::LINEAR as i32);
    gl.tex_parameter_i32(glow::TEXTURE_2D, glow::TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, glow::LINEAR as i32);
    gl.tex_parameter_i32(glow::TEXTURE_2D, glow::TEXTURE_WRAP_S, glow::CLAMP_TO_EDGE as i32);
    gl.tex_parameter_i32(glow::TEXTURE_2D, glow::TEXTURE_WRAP_T, glow::CLAMP_TO_EDGE as i32);
    gl.tex_image_2d(glow::TEXTURE_2D, 0, glow::RGBA as i32, 2, 2, 0, glow::RGBA, glow::UNSIGNED_BYTE, Some(&buffer));
    texture
}

struct ShaderInfo {
    program: Program,
    vao: VertexArray,
    sampler: UniformLocation,
    texture: Texture,
    xy: u32,
    uv: u32,
}

struct AppWrapper {
    shader: Arc<Mutex<ShaderInfo>>,
}

impl AppWrapper {
    unsafe fn new(cc: &CreationContext<'_>) -> Self {
        let gl = cc.gl.as_ref().unwrap();

        let vao = gl.create_vertex_array().unwrap();
        gl.bind_vertex_array(Some(vao));

        let vbo = gl.create_buffer().unwrap();
        gl.bind_buffer(glow::ARRAY_BUFFER, Some(vbo));

        let program = build_program(gl, &[(glow::FRAGMENT_SHADER, SRC_FRAGMENT), (glow::VERTEX_SHADER, SRC_VERTEX)]);
        let xy = gl.get_attrib_location(program, "xy").unwrap();
        let uv = gl.get_attrib_location(program, "uv").unwrap();
        gl.enable_vertex_attrib_array(xy);
        gl.enable_vertex_attrib_array(uv);
        // FIXME these vertex_attrib_pointer calls do nothing
        gl.vertex_attrib_pointer_f32(xy, 2, glow::FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        gl.vertex_attrib_pointer_f32(uv, 2, glow::FLOAT, false, 0, 48);

        gl.bind_vertex_array(None);

        Self {
            shader: Arc::new(Mutex::new(ShaderInfo {
                program,
                vao,
                sampler: gl.get_uniform_location(program, "sampler").unwrap(),
                texture: build_texture(gl),
                xy,
                uv,
            })),
        }
    }
}

impl App for AppWrapper {
    fn update(&mut self, ctx: &egui::Context, _: &mut Frame) {
        let style = egui::containers::Frame {
            fill: egui::Color32::LIGHT_BLUE,
            ..Default::default()
        };
        CentralPanel::default().frame(style).show(ctx, |ui| {
            let vertices: [f32; 6 * 2 * 2] = [
                /*
                 * order:
                 * 0   1,4
                 * 2,3  5
                 */
                -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, // xy
                0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 // uv
            ];

            let shader = self.shader.clone();
            ui.painter().add(PaintCallback {
                rect: Rect::EVERYTHING,
                callback: Arc::new(CallbackFn::new(move |_, painter| {
                    let gl = painter.gl();
                    let shader = shader.lock().unwrap();

                    unsafe {
                        gl.use_program(Some(shader.program));
                        gl.bind_vertex_array(Some(shader.vao));

                        gl.blend_func(glow::SRC_ALPHA, glow::ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

                        let ptr = vertices.as_ptr() as *const u8;
                        let mutated = std::slice::from_raw_parts(ptr, vertices.len() * 4);
                        gl.buffer_data_u8_slice(glow::ARRAY_BUFFER, mutated, glow::STATIC_DRAW);

                        gl.active_texture(glow::TEXTURE0);
                        gl.uniform_1_i32(Some(&shader.sampler), 0);
                        gl.bind_texture(glow::TEXTURE_2D, Some(shader.texture));

                        // FIXME must vertex_attrib_pointer here or it doesn't render correctly
                        // gl.vertex_attrib_pointer_f32(shader.xy, 2, glow::FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
                        // gl.vertex_attrib_pointer_f32(shader.uv, 2, glow::FLOAT, false, 0, 48);

                        gl.draw_arrays(glow::TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

                        gl.bind_vertex_array(None);
                        gl.use_program(None);

                    }
                }))
            });
        });
    }
}

fn main() {
    eframe::run_native("minimal example", NativeOptions::default(), Box::new(|cc| {
        Ok(Box::new(unsafe { AppWrapper::new(cc) }))
    })).unwrap();
}

What am I missing?

Running your code gives me: "error: process didn't exit successfully: target\debug\rust-playground.exe (exit code: 0xc0000005, STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION)
Segmentation fault"

https://github.com/emilk/egui/blob/master/examples/custom_3d_glow/src/main.rs Works for me without a segfault

Commenting in the vertex_attrib_pointer_f32 removes the segfault.

What makes you believe that the second call is not needed in the first place? Is it maybe just how OpenGL works?

What happens if you have multiple objects that use VAOs? Don't you need to call vertex_attrib_pointer before every draw call then? Or am I mistaken?

The VAO is supposed to store vertex_attrib_pointer so a single call is supposed to be sufficient: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704801/glvertexattribpointer-clarification

vertex_attrib_pointer describes how the buffer is read. A segfault without the second call isn't surprising because GL isn't reading the buffer correctly.
